# Current year displayed in the coming years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application a user can fill in a form to create learning goals for the classes they take each semester at school. This application should guide them through their full 4 years of their study.

In my form I've included

```
<p><%= Time.now.year %>/<%= Time.now.year + 1 %></p>
```

to get the current schoolyear. In the index of their learning goals is a table which lists the schoolyear in which their goals were created.

How do I get it to show 2013/2014 (the schoolyear in which it was created) when it's, for example, the year 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each goal has a `created_at` field, it should be as simple as using this for each goal:

```
<%= goal.created_at.year %>/<%= goal.created_at.year + 1 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save these values in database, so that u can retrieve them anytime, or you can simply use created_at date of the table(example:- goal.created_at if goals is the table)